# How to properly integrate Model with ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

There is a good example of ViewModel on Xamarin site https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/
but there is no model in the example, only View and ViewModel

Given it's ViewModel

```
namespace XamlSamples
{
    class ClockViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        DateTime dateTime;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ClockViewModel()
        {
            this.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
                {
                    this.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    return true;
                });
        }
```

And let's say this model

```
    namespace XamlSamples
    {
        public class ClockModel
        {
            public TimeSpan time;

            ...some other properties etc
```

how to I integrate them together and bind xaml controls to both ViewModel properties and Model properties?

I can duplicate them in ViewModel and set in it's constructor like

```
public ClockViewModel(ClockModel Model)
{
    time = Model.time;

    ... other properties same way
}
```

but it seems really ugly and wrong.

What is the best practice to do this? In aforementioned example ViewModel property is bound, but how do I bind Model properties or add them to ViewModel in a clean way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamlSamples;assembly=XamlSamples"
             x:Class="XamlSamples.ClockPage"
             Title="Clock Page">

  <Label Text="{Binding DateTime,
                        StringFormat='{0:T}'}"
         FontSize="Large"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
         VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Label.BindingContext>
      <local:ClockViewModel />
    </Label.BindingContext>
  </Label>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: For get 'Model' class working with `DataBinding` your Model need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Because implementing this in Model class will be wrong, because of separation of concerns principle. So having a class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and have same properties as Model isn't ugly, it separate different behavior.

Comment: Generally speaking, I often find that simply defining the similar/same properties in the model and view model separately is still the way to go even if it feels like you are repeating yourself a bit sometimes because the loose coupling it affords "usually" makes it worth it. It also provides a layer of indirection for cases where a view model maps to more than one model (aggregate views) or no model at all, etc. This obviously requires that you introduce some kind of "controller"/mapper in order to map models to/from view models.

Comment: I agree with blins comment, sometimes you have to repeat yourself to get loose coupling in MVVM way. But instead of duplicating values in constructor, you can use some mapping library. [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) is probably the best for you.